# permissions problem with creating a new text file from the python interpreter in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, installation

I'm attempting to create a .txt file as the output from a larger python script I'm running within ArcMap. The code I'm having trouble goes like this: `x = open('adfd.txt', 'w')`, and my error message says:

> Runtime error
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "`<string>`", line 1, in `<module>`
>   IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'adfd.txt'

I've tried this on ArcMap installations on other computers, as well as on non-Esri python interpreters on my own computer (Anaconda's Spyder), and it works fine there, so I'm pretty sure it's something going on with how my installation of ArcMap handles permissions. Does anyone know what might be going on here? I'd like to avoid reinstalling if possible, because that's a big pain with my student license.

Edit prompted by @AlexGIS: When I try to specify a different existing folder, I can change folders fine using arcpy.env.workspave, but I still get the same error message from the open command. When I try to make a new directory within ArcMap using os.mkdir I get a new error message:
`os.mkdir('asdfadfa') Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'asdfadfa'`

Maybe a new clue?

Comment: is that all your code?  Does `adfd.txt` exist?

Comment: There's a lot more, but that's all that's relevant to this problem (I can get every other line to run without any error messages). The file doesn't exist, but it should just create one, or wipe the old one if it does exist. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: If you go to the folder containing the file can you manually create a file? Or delete a file? Open the file?

Comment: Can you try specifying a different folder in which to create the file?  For example, create a new folder like c:\pytest and then change your code to be x = open('c:\\pytest\\adfd.txt', 'w') and see what happens.

Comment: @MaryBeth Yes, I can create, edit, and delete files from that directory manually from windows explorer.

Comment: @alexGIS When I try to specify a different existing folder, I can change folders fine using arcpy.env.workspave, but I still get the same error message from the open command. When I try to make a new directory within ArcMap using os.mkdir I get a new error message: `os.mkdir('asdfadfa')
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'asdfadfa'`

Maybe a new clue?

Comment: Are both folders on the same drive? Are they network drives, local drives? Network drives can act weird. Make sure you are testing on a local drive.

Comment: Hey LGelb - following the information in @MaryBeth and @alexGIS comments, what is the result of `os.getcwd()` from your python window? File objects opened without any preceding directory `"\\blah\\blah_folder"` will open in the current working directory, to my knowledge. Also, in ArcMap I think this defaults to the directory where your current .mxd document resides. Do you have permission to write in this folder? Best Luck.

Comment: @alexGIS All of this is taking place on my local C drive, and I'm the computer administer.

Comment: @Jim when I try `os.getcwd()`, it gives me back `'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32'`, despite my having specified `arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop'`. So it sounds like that's the problem, something going wrong when I try to specify the directory. Does anyone know why it might not change directories when I tell it to?

Comment: That could mean that installation program for ArcGIS  was "Run as Administrator", I think. If that's the case, maybe a reinstall is necessary?

Comment: @alexGIS Dang it, okay. So how do I install ArcGIS not as an administrator? I don't remember that being an option in the wizard.

Comment: Wait, I was wrong. You are fine. `'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32'` is the default directory when you start up ArcMap.

Comment: @alexGIS and LGelb - dudes...sorry to hear this if the reinstall is the solution, such a pain. If you have burned your student license code with the first install or have any additional difficulty I'd suggest reaching out to ESRI tech support, they should help you through it, you're a future customer.

Comment: @LGelb - What happens if you just specify the directory you want explicitly?  For example, `os.mkdir('c:\\testing\\asdfadfa')`

Comment: Earlier, you asked "_Does anyone know why it might not change directories when I tell it to?_"  Well, I don't think arcpy workspace changes the os directory.

Comment: @alexGIS Weird - that works fine! And when I specify the whole directory path I am able to use the open('asfdsda','w') command. I'm not sure why ArcMap wants full path names, but that's a way easier solution than a reinstall. Thanks so much for your help everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the working directory for `os` and `workspace`.

So, if your project directory was 'c:\testing', then you'd want to do something like this:

```
mydir = r'c:\testing'
os.chdir(mydir)
arcpy.env.workspace = mydir
```

Now when you make new files, that's the folder your new file will go.

Comment: Yes, that fixes it! Thank you so much for troubleshooting this for me! I wish I had the reputation to be able to give you an upvote.

Comment: Glad to help. @Jim's answers gave me some ideas to test out. I learned something too!